# window.applicationCache

Tags: html

Using HTML5 manifest file and cache is working fine.

I use window.applicationCache.update() to download the updated version. works fine.

How can I check to see if the manifest file has been updated so an update is available but not start downloading. Reason for this I want the user to allow the update or not as they may be in a bad network connection area.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
// Check if a new cache is available on page load.
window.addEventListener('load', function(e) {

  window.applicationCache.addEventListener('ondownloading', function(e) {

      window.applicationCache.abort();

  }, false);

}, false);
```

Just abort the download when you catch the `ondownloading` event.

Comment: Your answer starts the download - that is what I am doing already and as I said it all works fine. What I asked was how to check if available and then choose if to start download. Thew reason I want to allow choice is if in bad area on a mobile device the user will not want to start download.

Answer (score 0):

You can see all the available events [here](http://dev.w3.org/html5/spec-author-view/offline.html#appcacheevents)
There is not an event like that.
Browser checks the update of the manifest file and download the new added files automatically. You can check current state of the cache using its status property. It may have six different values. You can see the available status properties [here](http://motyar.blogspot.com/2011/09/handling-html5-application-cache-with.html). Then you can use applicationCache.swapCache() for swapping according to Your/User need.